# Clicking in input labels changes the whole content

Tags: javascript, html, css

## tab3 > brand-sidebar-wrapper > lacquer-type-wrapper > input

When I click here in input labels, hole .content div goes top and leave a lot of space at the bottom.

I tried to change js but there is no problem, that problem in html structure or css properties

```
<input class="selected" type="radio" data-price="0" name="radio" id="1" value="value" checked>
<label for="1" class="lacquer-type-checkbox tapicerka-color color-white">lakier bloku spluwaczki w kolorze białym</label>
<input data-invoice-row="3" data-price="300" type="radio" name="radio" id="2" value="value">
<label for="2" class="lacquer-type-checkbox tapicerka-color color-color">lakier bloku spluwaczki w kolorze tapicerki</label>
```

There is a page you can check problem by yourself. http://www.makromed.com.pl/konfigurator/ Tab3 > left sidebar > under list of colors

It appears when you choose Certus or Exima and Neo model

LIVE EXAMPLE
https://gyazo.com/20cfe8aa41cbf896784b3859915c5755

Comment: please consider adding relevant css code if thats the issue instead of link to the website

Comment: cant see what you asking, upload screenshot

Comment: https://gyazo.com/20cfe8aa41cbf896784b3859915c5755
@fahd4007

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the problem was in positioning parent input-holding div. I've given it "position:relative" and in magically way it works. If someone has a hypothesis how it works or share some article about this theme i'll be thankfull.